# opencart clone a module but wrong title in install page

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I cloned a module, renamed all named with a unique name of mine and renamed all filenames then upload them again to the module directory. I mean all files:module in contaroller, model,view and language files.
but when in go to the module lists, i cant find my module in the list.
Then i found that there is a row having my own new module but apeared with wrong name in the list.
for example there is module like newproducts, and another row below that, contains my module path but has a title as like as above row's name.
how and where i must set the name of my cloned module?
thank you

Comment: Show your `controller` code.

Comment: I think you might have not modified your language file properly.

Comment: i have soved the prblem . the language file was missing. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the language file was missing.